# How to load and svg using QGraphicsSvgItem.renderer().load?

Tags: python, user-interface, svg, pyqt5

I'm struggling to load an SVG image using PyQt5 `QGraphicsSvgItem.renderer().load`. MWE:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QGraphicsSvgItem, QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene)
        renderer = QSvgRenderer()
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        with open('test.svg') as fh:
            self.svg_data = fh.read()
        self.svg_data = QByteArray(self.svg_data.encode())
        self.svg_item = QGraphicsSvgItem()
        self.svg_item.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
        self.svg_item.renderer().load(self.svg_data)
        scene.addItem(self.svg_item)
        self.svg_item.setPos(-50, -50)

        self.svg_item2 = QGraphicsSvgItem('test2.svg')
        scene.addItem(self.svg_item2)
        self.svg_item2.setPos(50, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

While test.svg won't be loaded, test2.svg will. See here: Window with a single svg image test.svg is a blue rectangle, test2.svg is a black rectangle.

[image: Window with a single svg image]

What am I missing?

(NOTE: I am aware that I can load a svg using either `QGraphicsSvgItem('myfile.svg')` or `QGraphicsSvgItem(QSvgRenderer(my_svg_data))`, but I need to update the svg image in an existing object, so these methods wouldn't work for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when using the QSvgRenderer to load the .svg then the boundingRect of the QGraphicsSvgItem is not updated so nothing will be drawn. A possible solution is to use passing an empty string to the setElementId method to recalculate the geometry.

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene)

        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        self.svg_item = QGraphicsSvgItem()
        renderer = QSvgRenderer()
        self.svg_item.setSharedRenderer(renderer)
        with open("test.svg", "rb") as f:
            self.svg_item.renderer().load(f.read())
            self.svg_item.setElementId("")
        scene.addItem(self.svg_item)
        self.svg_item.setPos(-50, -50)

        self.svg_item2 = QGraphicsSvgItem("test2.svg")
        scene.addItem(self.svg_item2)
        self.svg_item2.setPos(50, 50)
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much! I was losing my mind trying to solve this problem. That's so absurdly counterintuitive, PyQt5 docs should state that.